# How can a surrounding div be the width of the inner text when the text is multiple lines?

Tags: css

Does anyone know how to make a surrounding div the width of the inner text?
I know i can set the div to display: inline-block; but this only works when your inner text is one line. Whenever the text is too big as the set max-width, the text starts on a second line and the width of the div is set as the max-width.
Even if there appears empty space now.

On this image, i want to apply this to the title with the pink transparent background.

https://img.skitch.com/20120206-e912tg8nwnrrbm5qqhxrb789qk.jpg

Many thanks!
Tom

My solution:
As i can't change the markup easily, the jquery solution did the trick indeed.
This is what i did:

```
$('#something h2').each(function(index) {
  $(this).css('width',$(this).find('a').css('width'));
});
```

Comment: How about you post some relevant markup and css, so we don't have to try and guess what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting it using jQuery?

`$('#UrDIV').css('width',$('#UrPText'))`

Maybe this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

considered wrapping `<div><span>my multiline text</span></div>` elements?